# Connection of c# with mysql

Tags: c#, mysql

I want to connect through code c# with wamp mysql but have some problem...

Under MySql of this line

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
```

I have error

> Error 1
>   The type or namespace name 'MySql' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have searched this problem from net but according to that solutions, my microsoft visual 2008 should have `mysql.data` and `web.data` in add reference but I don't have these references

If any one have any alternative solution then please help me

thanks

Answer (score 1):

you need to run through the [installation of the mysql connector libraries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-net-installation-windows.html), then add a reference to them in your project. after that, you should be able to add the using statement for `MySql.Data.MySqlClient`.

Comment: This proves very helpful for me thanks alot now i have no error in my sql connection again thanks

Comment: if it helped you solve your problem, please mark it as accepted to anyone else who comes along with the same question can find the correct answer easily.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add MySQL as a reference.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7314433t%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Of course, you'll have to install/download them first.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have the necessary assemblies referenced in your project (in Solution Explorer there is a References section.  You can view and add through that).

Also, if you do have the above complete, then you need to have `using yourNameSpace;`.

Comment: @ScottM. Ha for some reason I was in ASP.NET MVC3/Razor mode.  Weird.  Thanks for the correction, I've fixed it.